# Is there any way to pass anchor tag in an input string to a label

Tags: angular, input, angular7

I have a custom class for checkbox where label and input is defined along with the classes.

I am using that component in another class where i need to pass a label which contains a link also eg : Please accept the   to proceed .So  is it possible to pass label with above string that contains a link ?

customCheckbox.component.ts

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="checkboxForm">
  <label class="checkboxContainer">
    {{ label }} <input id="{{ id }}" type="checkbox" 
 [formControlName]="checkboxFormName" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

usage

```
<custom-checkbox
          id="_id"
          [checkboxForm]="checkboxForm"
          [nameOfControl]="checkboxFormName "
          label="{'Please accept the <a>terms and condition </a> .'" >
        </custom-checkbox>
```

so need this type of label .

Comment: you're taking the label & link via input? want to pass from one component to the other? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the text for label into the label's innerHTML.
Like this:

```
  label = 'This is normal,but <a href="https://www.google.com"> this is link</a>'

<label [innerHTML]="label"></label>
```

Comment: what do you mean by we can't use in it?

Comment: I mean to say as per requirement ... we are using some library created by other group  and we are not allowed to change it

Comment: can you share what library are you using and why you are not allowed to change it? Without looking into it would be really tough to provide alternatives

Comment: Its created by us only not any 3rd party.

Comment: The code mention in the main question is what written in the library . SO mainly is there any other way we can use apart from [innerHTML]

Comment: So any input for above ?

Comment: I didn't get time to look more deeply into this. There might be other solution like by using cdk, but it would be to much work such a simple task. You can try using another tag inside label tag (something like span) and then set the label value to that span tag using innerHtml. Other than those, i am able to give any other solution for it